# how to change global position value in method ( instantiateItem) in PagerAdapter

Tags: android, android-studio, sharedpreferences, android-pageradapter

i am trying to open the same image where i have closed the application by using sharedPreference i am saving the position but its not working. can anyone please help how to set the global position value.

```
    SharedPreferences pos = ctx.getSharedPreferences("forposition", MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor poseditor = pos.edit();
    if(pos1++ == 0)
    if(pos.getAll() != null) {
        position =  pos.getInt("pos", 0);
    }
```

Comment: where do you save these positions? Give more details

Comment: I am overriding instantiateItem(@NonNull ViewGroup container, int position) from PagerAdapter. I want to globally update to position value. Code include below  :                                                                                                                                                     public Object instantiateItem(@NonNull ViewGroup container, int position) {
}